# nativescript ListView Output is [ObjectObject]

Tags: listview, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

in my app am using native script ListView.in my ins.html page contain

```
<ListView [items]="views$ | async">
  <template let-view="item">
    <Label [text]="view.name"></Label>
  </template>
</ListView>
```

My result array is array of objects like this:

```
[{name:"abc", time:Date}, {name:"per", time:Date}]
```

when I compile this I got result as :

```
[ObjectObject]
[ObjectObject]
```

component.ts

```
constructor(){
this.views$ = store.let(getViews);
}
```

This view is updating using ngRx Store.
I am using nativeScript 2.5.0
How can I fix this problem?Any help will really helpful. I am new learner of native script.

Comment: Could you provide your js code, how do you get the array  (do you realy need the async pipe) ?

Comment: yes i need async pipe. am including my js code.

Comment: it means the view.name you got in the view is not a string, try to debug it

Comment: actually if i give this much <ListView [items]="views$ | async" (itemTap)="onClickView($event.view.bindingContext)"></ListView> it's working ie, same [ObjectObject].

Comment: you can get a reference for list liew from here https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/list-view.

Comment: in that no reference for async pipe